# What's the point of invoking sequential (synchronous) threads? Performance?

Tags: multithreading

So with synchronous threads, you have some threads waiting for other threads to finish.

As we can see in the observer pattern, etc.

An Example:

Thread 3 Waiting for Thread 2 to execute Method C
Thread 2 waiting for Thread 1 to execute Method B
Thread 1 execute Method A

Does this scenario have any benefit in performance in contrast with:

Thread 1
Executing Method A
Executing Method B
Executing Method C

Maybe they just do it for sake of spliting tasks according to behavior?

Comment: Could you show where you have seen this. I doubt that your example is actually what is happening. I doubt a new real thread is being started for each method call. More likely the same thread is being reused in each case.

Comment: It's also totally possible that this is basic [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)) being implemented in threads. For a single input item there is no real speed benefit, but if you have to go through a whole stack of them, ``Thread 2`` can do its work on ``item 1`` while ``thread 1`` works on ``item 2``, and then ``thread 3`` works on ``item 1`` while ``thread 2`` works on ``item 2`` and ``thread 1`` works on ``item 3``, and so on.